# Keep Session after node.js restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session

I am trying to get sessions to store passport sessions in express v4 and its not persisting after server restarts. I am already using `connect-mongo` so am unclear why this isn't persisting currently.

**db.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, config) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    session = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    fs = require('fs');

    mongoose.connect(config.db);

    mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function callback() {
        console.info('Database Connected!');
    });

    var sessionStore = new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection});
    module.exports = sessionStore;
};
```

**express.js**

```
module.exports = function (app, config, passport, dbConnect) {
    /* #Flash messaging and sessions ------------------------------------------------- */
    app.use(cookieParser('secretStrings'));
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secretStrings',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: null
        },
        rolling: true,
        store: dbConnect
    }));
    app.use(flash());

    /* #Set up passport ------------------------------------------------- */
    // use passport session
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
};
```

**Server.js**

```
/* #Mongo --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
var db = require('./app/db')(app, config);

/* #Express Settings --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
require('./config/express')(app, config, passport, db);
```

I believe the only logical explanation for this is that I have included the files in the wrong order so the sessions can't be saved?

Comment: Shouldn't `module.exports = sessionStore;` instead be `return sessionStore;` in your `db.js`?

Comment: lol of course it should. I had copy pasted that when I had it in express.js rather than db.js! Umm add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Although I wonder, should I delete this question as its a very specific  problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sessionStore` needs to be `return`ed in `db.js` instead of `module.exports = sessionStore;`.